# What is SQL equivalent to LINQ .All()

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2012

What would this look like in SQL (SQL Server if you want to be particular)?

```
// where people is a list of Person objects with property Name
bool bobs = people.All(p => p.Name == "Bob");
```

Comment: What does the `.All()` operator do?

Comment: Why do you want bob so much?

Comment: @ypercube: It returns true if the condition is true for all items.

Comment: Why a downvote? I would edit the question if I knew why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would check if there are any records that doesn't match the criteria:

```
not exists(select * from Persons where not Name = 'Bob')
```

As the rules for comparing to `null` are different between C# and SQL, you would need a condition for null values if the field allows them:

```
not exists(select * from Persons where Name <> 'Bob' or Name is null)
```

Comment: Can you rephrase that so it doesn't hurt my brain to read it? Maybe `Where Name <> 'Bob'`

Comment: Agreed, `Name <> 'Bob'` is far more intuitive than `not Name = 'Bob'`.

Comment: @Zane: I wrote it like that to make the condition recognisable from the original code, and to avoid any possible edge cases. Naturally you can use the `<>` operator if you know that the result is the same.

Comment: If what you said about `.All()` in your reply to @ypercube is correct, then your suggestion is not exactly equivalent. It would only work if there was no nulls. If `Persons.Name` had `'Bob'` and null entries (and nothing else), [your predicate would return true](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42902), whereas `.All()`, I suspect, would return false.

Comment: @AndriyM: Yes, you are right. The rules for comapring to `null` are different between C# and SQL.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Quite the opposite. *Not equal to* is far more intuitive than *less than or greater than*, you are just more used to one way of writing it. Familiarity doesn't mean that it's intuitive.

Comment: Using `not exists` fit my situation well, thanks all for the help.

Comment: How about just using the Where with NOT ? 
ex. select count(*) from table where not (any predicate)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what query exactly Linq will create but the equivalent in SQL is the `ALL` operator:

```
'Bob' = ALL (SELECT name FROM people)
```

Comment: In this case it does the same, but the SQL `all` operator is not equivalent to the `All` method. For example using a condition like `.All(p => p.name == p.nick)` doesn't easily translate to using the `all` operator.

Comment: @Guffa. true. And my `ALL` translation will yield different results to your `NOT EXISTS` if the `name` has null values. If you are sure that Linq translates the `All()` to not exists, I should remove my answer.